# Font requests to CloudFront are "(cancelled)"

Tags: amazon-s3, fonts, amazon-cloudfront, webfonts

I have a CloudFront distribution at (`static.example.com`) which has an S3 bucket as Origin. I am using this distribution to store all the artifacts for client code (JavaScript files, stylesheets, images and **fonts**).

All the requests to JavaScript files, stylesheets and images succeed without any problem however, requests to font files have the status `cancelled` in Google Chrome.

Here is how I request those fonts:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Material Design Icons;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(https://static.example.com/5022976817.eot);
    src: url(https://static.example.com/5022976817.eot) format("embedded-opentype"), 
        url(https://static.example.com/611c53b432.woff2) format("woff2"), 
        url(https://static.example.com/ee55b98c3c.woff) format("woff"),
        url(https://static.example.com/cd8784a162.ttf) format("truetype"), 
        url(https://static.example.com/73424aa64e.svg) format("svg")
}
```

The request to the `svg` font file is ok, but the other ones are not ok.

[image]

What have I done wrong? Every file in the S3 bucket has `public-read` ACL.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: I fixed it by looking at a ton of articles/documentation pages on the internet and I simply cannot remember the exact steps to fix this. However, here's something that I know for sure I gave a read: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-cors It's late where I am so I will try to wrap up the knowledge I acquired in an answer to this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is an issue with CORS preventing to load the fonts from a different domain.

You need to:

1. **Enable CORS on your S3 bucket:**

Go to the s3 bucket and on the `Permissions` tab select `CORS configuration`, add the permission with your `AllowedOrigin`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://static.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

You can add multiple `AllowedOrigin`:

```
<AllowedOrigin>https://static.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedOrigin>http://static.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedOrigin>https://example.com</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedOrigin>http://otherexample.com</AllowedOrigin>
```

Or use a wildcard:

```
<AllowedOrigin>*.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
```

2. **Whitelist the appropriate headers on CloudFront to be passed to S3:**

Go to the `Behaviors` tab on your CloudFront distribution and select `Create Behavior` and add the patter you want:

```
Path Pattern: 5022976817.eot
Cache Based on Selected Request Headers: Whitelist
```

Add the following headers to the whitelisted headers:

- `Access-Control-Request-Headers`
- `Access-Control-Request-Method`
- `Origin`

You can test that CORS is working properly with curl:

```
curl -X GET -H "Origin: https://static.example.com" -I https://static.example.com/5022976817.eot
```

Everything is ok if you get a response header like:

```
access-control-allow-origin: https://static.example.com
```